# How do you add the "you are here" marker to Bing Maps Control

Tags: bing-maps, windows-phone

How do you add the "you are here" marker to the Bing Maps control? On the phone this is represented as a circle within a square and then there is an outer circle representing the location accuracy.
It looks like you could do it with a pushpin and a polgon but I'm hoping there is an easier/better way

Answer (score 4):

You can use the GeoCoordinateWatcher class, which gives your current location, and then add a simple pushpin. I don't think the pushpin is a bad choice and/or a hard one to use.

```
GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();

GeoCoordinate loc = watcher.Position.Location;

if (loc.IsUnknown == true)
{
    // Cannot retrieve the GPS position
    return;
}

MyBingMap.SetView(loc, 17);

MapLayer pushPinLayer = new MapLayer();

MyBingMap.Children.Add(pushPinLayer);

Pushpin p = new Pushpin();

p.Content = "YOU ARE HERE";
p.Location = loc;

pushPinLayer.AddChild(p, loc, PositionOrigin.BottomLeft);
```

Answer (score 2):

You asked two questions and Tuco has given you a good answer to the first one: how to add the pushpin. Here's the answer to your second question: how to style it.

To get the pushpin to look like a yellow dot in a black diamond with a white nimbus, you need to define this style and apply it to the pushpin. I could also tell you how to style white numbers centred on a black circle with a white nimbus, but then I'd have to kill you.

```
xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps"

<Style x:Key="CurrentLocationPushpinStyle" TargetType="m:Pushpin">
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFF4F4F5" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate>
        <Grid>
          <Rectangle Fill="Black" Height="25" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="2" Width="25" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
              <CompositeTransform Rotation="45" TranslateX="-10" TranslateY="11"/>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
          </Rectangle>
          <Ellipse Fill="Yellow" Height="11" Stroke="Yellow" Width="11">
            <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
              <CompositeTransform TranslateX="-10" TranslateY="11"/>
            </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
          </Ellipse>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

A yellow dot is soooo last year. Mango uses a blue dot.

Comment: Thanks, I think it uses a dot that is the colour of your theme mine is currently green

Comment: The green dot is Mango beta 2. I have the green dot now but I use the blue theme.